# Projection: Argument 'crs': Invalid type when displaying ee.Image

Tags: python, google-earth-engine

I'm starting with GEE and I try to display in a Jupyter notebook a simple image of a small area to see if I get it right.

I followed the instruction of the documentation and write the following:

```py
img = ee.Image('UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2015')

ee.Image(url=img.getThumbUrl(({
    'bands':['treecover2000', 'loss', 'gain'],
    'min': 100,
    'max': 1500,
    'region': [[[-107.36, 38.68],[-107.36, 38.32],[-106.22,38.32],[-106.22,38.68]]]
})))
```

I was expecting a small area to e displayed but instead I get the following error :

> EEException: Projection: Argument 'crs': Invalid type. Expected: String. Actual: Type<`Boolean`>.

which is strange because I didn't even set the `crs`argument

Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same issue happened to me while running the below code .The solution worked  for me is to downgrade my python version.Im not sure whether the same will work for you

```
from __future__ import print_function
import ee
import ee.mapclient

ee.Initialize()

# Get a download URL for an image.
image1 = ee.Image('CGIAR/SRTM90_V4')
path = image1.getDownloadUrl({
    'scale': 30,
    'crs': 'EPSG:4326',
    'region': '[[-120, 35], [-119, 35], [-119, 34], [-120, 34]]'
})
print(path)
```

Comment: Downgrade to which version?

Comment: @NikolasStevenson-Molnar I have tried on python 3.6.8 and the code above works fine for me. But the same doesn't work on conda environment as well as colab because the latest version is 3.8. something .

Answer (score 1):

I don't get the same error when I run your script. It has some other problem though. `img.getThumbUrl()` doesn't return an `ee.Image`, so you shouldn't try to cast it to one. If you also drop the `url=`, it runs fine for me. The below runs for me:

```
import ee
ee.Initialize()
img = ee.Image('UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2015')

img.getThumbUrl({
    'bands':['treecover2000', 'loss', 'gain'],
    'min': 100,
    'max': 1500,
    'region': [[[-107.36, 38.68],[-107.36, 38.32],[-106.22,38.32],[-106.22,38.68]]]
})
```

Comment: I prefer your version because it's lighter but I'm still rising the `Projection: Argument 'crs': Invalid type` error. It is linked to definition of the 'region' parameter

Comment: What version of the earthengine-api do you use? My script runs just fine for me (cannot check my API version right now though).

Comment: earthengine-api          0.1.212